# LAravel 505 error

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

This has been giving a

> 404 page error not found

and i don't know why.

```
 public static function getGeneration($currentParent, $rootParent){
    // dd($rootParent);
    $user = User::where("username", $currentParent)->first();

    $generation =[];
    $x = 0;
    $bool = true;

     while ($bool) {

        if($x==0){
            $generation[$x] = (User::where("username", $user->sponsor_username)
                                ->firstOrfail())
                                ->sponsor_username;
        }else{
            $generation[$x] = (User::where("username", $generation[$x-1])
                                ->firstOrfail())
                                ->sponsor_username;

        }

        if( $x > 0 ){
            if($news = $generation[$x] == $rootParent){
                dd($news);
                $bool = false;

            }
        }


        $x++;
     }
     return $generation;
}
```

what this method basicaly does is go through a database and find out who brought a particular user into a system, because is user has a sponsor_username against it on the database, the last if statement is meant to stop when it discovers that it has reached the root user.

Comment: where are you calling this function from? 404 error means Laravel can't find the route you're trying to access. It probably has nothing to do with the code you've shared here

Comment: Just a suggestion, but using `firstOrFail()` will trigger a 404 if you're not in debug mode. Does your `User` query always return a model?